# Determining if a function is stand-alone or part of a type class

Tags: haskell

When I come across a function, is there a general way to determine if it's completely stand-alone or a part of a type class? For instance:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

This is the method I have developed to find the answer:

1. Go to GHCi and do `:info` on all the listed class constraints, in this case `:info Integral` and `:info Num`.
2. Check if any of them lists the function.
3. If it does, it's part of that type class. If it doesn't, it's a stand-alone function (which is the case for `forIntegral`).

Is my method sound? Does it work in general?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do `:info` on the function directly.

```
Prelude> :info fromInteger
class Num a where
  ...
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
        -- Defined in `GHC.Num'

Prelude> :info fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
```

As you see, `fromInteger` belongs to the `Num` typeclass, while `fromIntegral` does not.

Answer (score 7):

There's an easier way, compare the difference in output for `:info fromIntegral` and `:info fromInteger`:

```
> :info fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
> :info fromInteger
class Num a where
  ...
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
        -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
```

See how `fromInteger` is specified as part of a type class, but `fromIntegral` is not?  That's how you can tell.